# JQuery addClass through function on CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

I'm sure this is an obvious and stupid mistake but I can't seem to add a class on a function call:

https://codepen.io/Yonkai/pen/WZyMJw?editors=1111

The problem is on line 28 in the JS section:

```
 function smove(){
  $(".creatures p:nth-child(2)").addClass("selected");
}
```

When I call the function it doesn't change "Rodan" like I expect it would in the html, here (uncompilled from pug), I expected it to turn yellow by adding class:

```
.selected{
  color:yellow;
}
```

into:

```
<div class="creatures">
  <p class="bodytext">Mothra</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Destroyah</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Rodan</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Kim Jung Un</p>
  <p class="bodytext">King Ghidora</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Godzilla</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `When I call the function` - you don't call the function

Comment: I was calling it through the console. You can call globally scope functions that way.

Comment: `div .bodytext` has a HIGHER specificity than `.selected` - ahh, an answer has been posted to say that, didn't see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make you `.selected` selector in css more specific like `div .selected`

currently `div .bodytext` has more weitage over `.selected`

[Update Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzBPvX?editors=1111)

You can read about css specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: That seemed to be the issue!

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the function somewhere

```js
 smove();

function smove(){
  $(".creatures p:nth-child(2)").addClass("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="creatures">
  <p class="bodytext">Mothra</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Destroyah</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Rodan</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Kim Jung Un</p>
  <p class="bodytext">King Ghidora</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Godzilla</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work for you on CodePen? It doesn't work for me. Either adding it to the script page or calling through console.